# Restricting page access

Tags: plugins, content-restriction

I need to restrict access to a page in a wordpress site for everyone but registered users. I have looked at a couple of plugins, and although they work well, they don't quite fit my solution... The page I am trying to restrict is based on a page template that itself has some hard coded forms that will interact with a backend server. The plugins I have tried block the WP content, but I can still see the forms from the template.

I need:

1. show login and registration box in-line on the blocked page that I can style (not redirect to standard WP logon)
2. upon successful registration, then the page will show the content including the template content.
   I hope this is clear and that someone can help me with either a better plugin, or a code solution.

Thanks

Comment: Asking for plugins for thrid party software is off-topic. Asking for a code solution without showing us that you have tried to code at your own first ... that is "do the job for me" format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate output conditionally with trivial [`is_user_logged_in()`](http://queryposts.com/function/is_user_logged_in/) check in template.

Comment: I had an alternative using <?php if ( current_user_can('subscriber')) { ?>
   <p>You are a subscriber</p>
  <?php } ?>
But your solution is preferred, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with wp_login_form, something like this

```
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() and <any-other-condition>){
    $args = array(
        'echo'           => false,
        'redirect'       => esc_url($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]), 
        'label_username' => __( 'Username' ),
        'label_password' => __( 'Password' ),
        'label_remember' => __( 'Remember Me' ),
        'label_log_in'   => __( 'Log In' ),
        'id_username'    => 'user_login',
        'id_password'    => 'user_pass',
        'id_remember'    => 'rememberme',
        'id_submit'      => 'wp-submit',
        'remember'       => true,
        'value_username' => NULL,
        'value_remember' => false
    );
    $loginform = wp_login_form( $args );
}
...continue and do whatever with $loginform
```